# Clickhouse ASOF left Join right table Nullable column is not implemented

Tags: sql, join, clickhouse

I have tried to find the answer in the doc and in other forums but failed to understand.
Doc: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/join/ [CH doc](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/join/)

My tables are similar to: [stack overflow question](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/join/)

I would like to get the order price right before a trade (and also return the order ts and info regarding the trades).

Using the code below, I get the following error: *SQL Error [48]: ClickHouse exception, code: 48,DB::Exception: ASOF join over right table Nullable column is not implemented*

What I have tried is the condition "IS NOT NULL" but it didn't do anything.

Code:

```
WITH 
orders as(
    SELECT order_timestamp, order_price, product_id
    FROM order_table
    WHERE
        ( order_timestamp >= toInt32(toDateTime64('2022-01-02 10:00:00.000', 3))*1000
            AND order_timestamp <= toInt32(toDateTime64('2022-01-02 12:00:00.000', 3))*1000)
        AND product_id = 'SPXFUT'
        AND order_timestamp IS NOT NULL),
trades as (
    SELECT 
       trade_timestamp,
       price
    FROM trades_table
    WHERE
         trade_timestamp >= toInt32(toDateTime64('2021-12-02 10:00:00.000', 3))*1000 AND trade_timestamp <= toInt32(toDateTime64('2021-12-02 12:00:00.000', 3))*1000
         AND product_id = 'SPXFUT'
         AND trade_timestamp IS NOT NULL),
results as(
SELECT 
    tt.product_id,
    tt.trade_timestamp,
    tt.price,
    o.order_timestamp,
    o.order_price
    FROM trades tt
    ASOF LEFT JOIN orders o
    ON (tt.product_id = o.product_id ) AND (tt.trade_timestamp >= o.order_timestamp ))
SELECT *
FROM results
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current implementation of `ASOF LEFT JOIN` requires that the right side column used in inequality to be a non-nullable type. As the types comes from the table definition (and your order_table must have a definition of `order_timestamp` like `Nullable(Int64)`), ClickHouse will refuse to run with the exception like `ClickHouse exception, code: 48,DB::Exception: ASOF join over right table Nullable column is not implemented`.

As a solution, you can wrap `o.order_timestamp` with `assumeNotNull` function in the ASOF LEFT JOIN condition:

```
ON (tt.product_id = o.product_id ) AND (tt.trade_timestamp >= assumeNotNull(o.order_timestamp) ))
```

But you shall consider the behavior of `assumeNotNull` ([documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/functions-for-nulls/#assumenotnull)) - it will give a non-null value for the type (default value), which might give wrong results for the cases where `o.order_timestamp` is null (`assumeNotNull` is implementation specific and can bring more problems - [assumeNotNull and friends](https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-functions/assumenotnull-and-friends/)).

Another solution is to use `ifNull` and provide a suitable replacement for the missing values, avoiding potential problems that `assumeNotNull` brings:

```
ON (tt.product_id = o.product_id ) AND (tt.trade_timestamp >= ifNull(o.order_timestamp,0) ))
```

And the last suggestion is to change the column datatype to a non-nullable one:

```
ALTER TABLE order_table MODIFY COLUMN order_timestamp <TypeName>;
```

But this depends on your use case - if it is a requirement that `order_timestamp` has to accept null values, I would recommend to adopt the second solution.

Comment: One more probable solution is use join with subquery `ASOF LEFT JOIN (select ...., assumeNotNull(...) from orders where ... is not null) o` assumeNotNull is safe to use in this case because we cut nulled values using where.

Comment: I have tested out your suggestion Anselmo and it is working perfectly. Thanks for your contribution. I believe that "assumeNotNull()" is not an issue as I specify the condition "not null" in the WHERE statement ?

Denny Crane, thanks for your remark ! I haven't tried this approach yet, if I do, I'll post an update.